# cfhttp showing "403 Forbidden" for correct URLs

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, http-status-code-403, cfml, cfhttp

I am making a cfhttp call to a URL.The URL is opening fine on my machine. The URL is also not an SSL encrypted URL.But I am getting cfhttp.statuscode as "403 Forbidden". Please Let me know is there any way to fix the issue. 
Codes :
[image: Error Detail]
{

```
<cfhttp redirect="no" url="#desturl#" method="GET" timeout="20" userAgent="#useragent_txt#"/>
```

}

Comment: I've encountered this sometimes if I don't send a recognised user-agent string with my request via CFHTTP. I presume it's some sort of measure to block bots... or people scraping the page ;-)

Comment: @AdamCameron I have sent the useragent ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)") also , but still its showing the same error.

Comment: Can you surf to the URL from a browser on the ColdFusion server?

Comment: 403 Forbidden is not limited to pages/sites that are configured for SSL. For example, both Apache and IIS will return 403 Forbidden when directory browsing is turned off and there is no document that matches the default document configuration in the directory being accessed. Whenever I receive a 403 error, I always assume it is a permissions issues until proven it is not (can't recall a time where it wasn't). Is it safe to assume that you can hit the ULR in question directly from a browser window?

Comment: @ScottStroz: Yes i can browse that url from my browser .

Comment: Is it a public URL? One we may be able to hit to help you out? Is there any kind of authentication in front of the URL (maybe Windows authentication)?

Comment: @ScottStroz Yes this is a public URL: http://www.sears.com/active-care-active-care-osprey-4410-power-handicap/p-SPM1655544201P?prdNo=3&blockNo=3&blockType=G3
Please check.

Comment: Not that it helps but I created a quick test page and made a `cfhttp` call to that URL and also get Forbidden. Using ColdFusion 9.0.1

Comment: Finally any one please suggest me this is possible or not.

Comment: Do you need to have the extra info in the query string? Using http://www.sears.com/active-care-active-care-osprey-4410-power-handicap/p-SPM1655544201P in cfhttp it worked as expected in CF 10.

Comment: Actually, even with the query string data it worked in CF 10.

Comment: It even worked for me in CF9, version 9,0,1,274733

Comment: @ScottStroz So is this problem with CF9 only, I am not sure.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy it worked for me locally on CF 9.01. I am working on trying to test on CF 9.0.2

Comment: @ScottStroz: Thanks , I will update my CF server and try .

Comment: 9.0.2 with latest hotfixes works as well - http://www.boyzoid.com/stuff/test.cfm

Comment: Here is the code I used `<cfhttp method="get" url="http://www.sears.com/active-care-active-care-osprey-4410-power-handicap/p-SPM1655544201P?prdNo=3&blockNo=3&blockType=G3" >

<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">`

Comment: @ScottStroz: Thanks a lot, this worked for me also . previously I was sending the useragent , now after removing this it is working fine.

Comment: I had this problem with a site that got proxied through CloudFlare DNS